# Spring hateoas methodOn with inherited method

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I am trying to use Spring hateoas to resolve the URL of an inherited endpoint from an abstract controller.

I think giving the code first will make the question easier to understand.

Here is my abstract controller :

```
package com.stackoverflow.question.spring.rest.controllers;

import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

public class AbstractController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/cat", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Resource<String> cat() {
        return new Resource<>("cat");
    }
}
```

Here is my controller which use methodOn :

```
package com.stackoverflow.question.spring.rest.controllers;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;

import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = { "application/json; charset=utf-8" })
public class TestController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Resource<String> test() {
        return new Resource<>("test", linkTo(
                methodOn(TestController.class).cat()).withRel("cat"), linkTo(
                methodOn(TestController.class).uglyfix()).withRel("uglyfix"));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uglyfix", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Resource<String> uglyfix() {
        return new Resource<>("ugly fix", linkTo(TestController.class).slash(
                "cat").withRel("cat"));
    }

}
```

This is what i get when I go to /resources/test :

```
{
    "content": "test",
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "cat",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/resources/cat"
        },
        {
            "rel": "uglyfix",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/resources/test/uglyfix"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what I would expect to have and what I want hateoas to do :

```
{
    "content": "test",
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "cat",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/resources/test/cat"
        },
        {
            "rel": "uglyfix",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/resources/test/uglyfix"
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, I could do what I did in the endpoint uglyfix but I do not like this solution because it mean that if I change my request mapping in my abstract controller, I will have to change the code of my TestController.

Maybe adding @RequestMapping(value="test") at the top of my abstract controller will fix my problem, but I do not want this solution neither because I want to use my extends my abstract controller with more than one controller.

Is there a clean way to do, what I expect ?

Answer (score 1):

I feel a bit stupid because I just migrate Spring hateoas from 0.9.0.RELEASE 0.17.0.RELEASE and it fixed my problem.